# Filter calendar by each location without creating a view by hand

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-calendar

I have a room reservation calendar that tracks 12 different rooms/locations. I need to be able to filter that calendar by each room. In the past we have created a view for each value of location (a choice column in our case).

This is inefficient, since if we add a room or change the name of a room we need to go in and change the views.

Is there a way to have an automatic list of the possible locations from the choice list and automatically filter based upon those?

Answer (score 0):

Create a view based on the Current events view (or even using the Current Events view) and letting users click the Location filter heading to let them filter as they want. The default views give you that functionality.

Comment: I need to be able to see a month or a week for just one specific room. The current event view seems to be only for one day. I can't find a way to make it be for different periods of time. Also I can't tell what I'm looking at with the current events view -- no header or anything to help me understand what I'm looking at!

Comment: Current shows everything from today out a couple weeks i think. The short answer is there isn't any functionality like that OOTB, you'd have to roll your own code to create a dynamic view like that. Some grouping in one of the list views would get you close and give users the ability to then filter on the data as necessary.